# Dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python

How would I remedy the following error?

```
for item in data:
    if data[item] is None:
        del data[item]

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

It doesn't actually seem to affect my operation, so I'm wondering if perhaps I should just ignore this error?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=RuntimeError%3A+dictionary+changed+size+during+iteration

Comment: You don't want to change things while you are iterating over them.

Comment: *It doesn't actually seem to affect my operation*--Then you are doing at least two things wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You have to move changing dictionary to another vairable:

```
changing_data = data
for item in data:
  if changing_data[item] is None:
    del changing_data[item]
data = changing_data
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a matter of needing to change the item to be iterated over from the dictionary to the keys of the dictionary:

```
for key in data.keys():
    if data[key] is None:
        del data[key]
```

Now it doesn't complain about iterating over an item that has changed size during its iteration.

Comment: It works in python 2.x, but not in 3.x. :(

Comment: However, ... if you convert the keys() to a list, then it will work in python 3.x.: `for key in list(data.keys()):`  Because python 3.x uses *views* of the data, when you delete something from the dict, then what the view sees also changes.  But a list of the keys does not change as you delete things from the dict, so  iterating over a list of keys does not cause an iteration problem.

Comment: @7stud that makes sense. Would you want to post your own answer here describing this all and I'll accept yours?